# Turbolinks creating an issue AddThis widget

Tags: ruby-on-rails, turbolinks, addthis

For some reason turbolinks is causing the AddThis widget not to appear when the page is loaded for the first time. If you click refresh it will appear. When I remove turbolinks there is no problem with AddThis appearing. Why is turbolinks causing this?

In application.html.erb:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//s7.addthis.com/js/300/addthis_widget.js#pubid=ra-583665b72cde5f5c"></script>
```

In show.html.erb

```
<div class="addthis_inline_share_toolbox"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the problem is you didn't use the [javascript_include_tag](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/AssetTagHelper/javascript_include_tag)

Turbolinks has a caching mechanism that can cause some JS libs not to behave properly, [look here](https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks#understanding-caching)